# c++ custom operator(+=) behaves in an unpredicted way

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
Kvector::Kvector(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y),z(z) {};

Kvector& Kvector::operator+(const Kvector& other) {
    return Kvector(x + other.x, y + other.y, z + other.z);
};

Kvector& Kvector::operator*(const Kvector& other) {
    return Kvector((x == 0) ? 0 : x*other.x, 
                   (y == 0) ? y * other.y : 0,
                   (z == 0) ? 0 : z * other.z);
};

Kvector& Kvector::operator*(const float other) {
    return Kvector(x * other, y * other, z * other);
};

void Kvector::operator+=(const Kvector& other) {
    x += other.x;
    y += other.y;
    z += other.z;
};
```

Above is the definition of the operators for struct called Kvector( struct with float x y z, three simple objects and that's it).

If my understanding of the code is correct following code should print 29 29 29. And it does so.

```
Kvector a(1,1,1);
a = a*29;
cout<<"poss "<<a.x << " "<<a.y<< " "<< a.z<<endl;
```

However if I try

```
Kvector a(1,1,1);
a += a*29;
cout<<"poss "<<a.x << " "<<a.y<< " "<< a.z<<endl;
```

It prints 1 1 1 for some reason. 
So I tried the below code instead.

```
Kvector a(1,1,1);
a = a+ a*29;
cout<<"poss "<<a.x << " "<<a.y<< " "<< a.z<<endl;
```

The code above prints the following

poss -1.07374e+008 -1.07374e+008 -1.07374e+008

I expected it to print 30 30 30 since a= (1,1,1) + (1,1,1) * 29 = (1,1,1) + ( 29, 29,29) = (30,30,30)

I would deeply appreciate an explanation on this behavior.
Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: If you are using MSVC++, the first thing to do is go to project settings and ask the compiler to *disable* all language extensions. Your code is not even valid C++. Formally it is not compilable. Your compiler accepted it because of the extensions being enabled. And in this case that extension led to code that simply doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, what is the point of branching on `x == 0` (and `y == 0` and `z == 0`) in the first operator `*`? Why not just multiply it without branching? Your second operator `*` does not branch for zero. Why does the first one do?

Comment: I was working on division. Somehow the concept, don't devide by zero got mixed with multiplication in my brain. Sorry about that. What do you mean that my code is not even valid c++? I thought I was writing c++?

Comment: In C++ it is illegal to attach non-cont references to temporary objects. Your operators `+` and `*` do exactly that in their `return` statements. This is invalid, non-compilable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

operator+= signature is :

```
Kvector& Kvector::operator+=(const Kvector& other) 
{
  x+=other.x; 
  y+=other.y; 
  z +=other.z;

  return *this;
};
```

It's also a good practice to implement + usign += to reduce code duplication and as a free function.

```
Kvector Kvector::operator+(const Kvector& a, const Kvector& b) 
{
  Kvector result(a);
  result += b;
  return result;
};
```

Currently your code is returning a Kvector& for operator+ which return a reference to a local variable, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: `+` can be written in one line as `return Kvector(a) += b;`, if one prefers it.

Comment: thank you for the good technique. I really appreciate it. Wish I could vote your answer up and all others for their effort but I can't since my reputation is only something like 3. Thank you.

Comment: @AndreyT: But that can be less that optimal and the form that @JoelFalcou supplied is one of the reasons that I upvoted. It explicitly returns the copy made rather than the result of `operator+=`. While these _should_ be the same thing being explicit makes it easier on the optimizer to use [N]RVO and eliminate the temporary. Being explicit especially helps when the implementation of `op+=` is not inline: what if the implementation of `op+=` didn't return a reference to `*this`? the compiler can't tell from the signature.

Comment: Just a nit, but it is only a convention that `operator+=` return a reference, rather than a `void`.  There's nothing formally that requires it.  (Of course, it's best to follow such well established conventions.)

Comment: @Charles Bailey: It depends. I'd say that NRVO is still more "exotic" than plain RVO.

Comment: @AndreyT: Yes, but in the case where `op+=` isn't inlined the options are NRVO vs no RVO at all as you have to copy a return value that is a reference, you can't influence where that object is made. The posted version may not be always result in fewer temporaries than the `return X(x) += y;` variation but I have never seen it result in more.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Well, are you saying that my variant somehow formally violates the pre-conditions for RVO, thus making RVO impossible? Or are you just saying that the more convoluted `return` statement in my variant is more likely to confuse the compiler and make it skip RVO (even though RVO is formally allowed in that case)?

Comment: @AndreyT: Exactly. [n]RVO is when a temporary or local automatic variable can be eliminated in a function body by constructing that object in the space reserved for the return object, eliminating the copy implicit in the `return` statement. An expression that is a function call returning a reference is an lvalue referring to an object that already exists, the calling function cannot influence its placement so must copy its value in the return. If the function is fully inlined and the compiler can see that the return value refers to a local object it may be able to optimize under "as if" rule.

Comment: I came back to stackoverflow to ask one more question on another topic and I found this. Ohhhhh. Good stuff to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
Kvector& Kvector::operator+(const Kvector& other){return Kvector    (x+other.x,y+other.y,z+other.z); };
Kvector& Kvector::operator*(const Kvector& other){return Kvector((x==0)?0: x*other.x,(y==0)?    y*other.y:0,(z== 0)? 0: z*other.z); };
Kvector& Kvector::operator*(const float other){return Kvector( x*other,y*other,z*other); };
```

You return reference to the temporary object. Incorrect. Replace `Kvector&` with `Kvector` in return-type.

Answer (score 0):

You should not return a local variable in a method as reference. Result can be unexpected. Many c++ compiler should give you warning about this, such as vc++11

Comment: thank you for the advice. I will remember not to return local variables the next time.